# Computers displaying an unwanted password change prompt

Tags: windows, group-policy, password

We run a small network of users from a central SBS 2008 server that handles group policy & AD. Most of our users operate under a policy that propts them for a password change every 6 months as a security measure, with a few administrator accounts & terminal machines not using the policy for the sake of ease as they are needed all the time. Recently all machines regardless of policy have started asking for a password change out of schedule. Some PCs run Windows 7 & some XP, though the password prompts don't seem to discriminate between OS. What could this be down to?

Many thanks

Comment: Make users change passwords every 6 months but the most critical passwords are never changed? What's the point?

Comment: simply that there are only two people in the company with access to the administrator passwords so we feel they are safe, whereas we have a team of fairly computer-illiterate staff so we like to at least try and keep them as secure as possible...

Answer (score 2):

As a first step, have you tried running the RSOP(Resultant Set of Policy) snap-in to see if there is another policy involved.  rsop.msc will run the tool.

Comment: will check this, is something I have not yet encountered so thank you much

Answer (score 0):

You may have picked up some malware. Some of them pop those up to collect more passwords... Try running some very recent anti-malware software.

Comment: Have checked for this and we are definitely malware free as well as having the absolute latest virus definitions in the anti-virus. Think it's a problematic group policy perhaps, but will need to keep investigating. thanks